# how to apply user defined function on variables just like built in function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback, user-defined-functions

I am trying to make a user-defined function to work on variables by using the dot(.) operator rather than sending as the parameter. So in my program, I have an array of integer and I need to perform for each on that not by using forEach built-in function. I know this sound rubbish. So I have created a function named somefunc and have a variable called arr.

code that I have done

```
var somefunc = function()
{
   console.log('this function executed');
}
var arr=[1,2];
arr.somefunc();
```

The code I am trying to mimic

```
var friends = ["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"];
friends.forEach(function (eachName, index){
console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName); // 1. Mike, 2. Stacy, 3. Andy, 4. Rick
});
```

I want to execute a function like that forEach.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Prototypes here. Add `somefunc` to a prototype of a JS built in Array type.

```js
    Array.prototype.somefunc = function() {
        this.forEach(function (eachName, index) {
              console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName);
        });
        // or you can use other ways to itarate over all array elemets
        // like a simple for loop for (let i=0; i < this.length; i++) {...}
        // 'this' here refers to an array you are running somefunc on
    }
    var friends = ["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"];
    friends.somefunc();
```

Each function like `forEach` , `map` , etc. is also present in `prototype` of an `Array`, they are properties of a `prototype`. You can see it by doing `console.log(Array.prototype);` You can see that the `prototype` of `Array` has many built in methods available to you out of the box which you can call by using the dot. So you just add your own functions alongside with them by assigning a new function property to `Array.prototype` as show in a snippet above.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add your function to array proptotype to create desired behavior. Access the current array using this.

```
Array.prototype.customIterator = function() {
  // this.forEach(() => {})
}
```